# Why is the upper bound of this statement always incremented by 1?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, notation, summation

Why is "for j = 1 to  n" translate to this? Why is the upper bound always incremented by 1?

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}1 $$

Why isn't it 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n1 $$

"for j = 1 to n" is written in pseudo code btw for algorithm analysis. Or is there a + 1 because of the final condition check when using summations to count the frequency count of for loops?

Comment: It should be what you say it is. I'm not sure why you need to increment it by 1. Are you programming something, by any chance?

Comment: Can you provide the context? Where did you see this? Sometimes in programing 0 is the first number, which could cause the difference in notation.

Comment: Saw it in a powerpoint, its written in pseudocode for algorithm analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are backwards.  In BASIC, For j=1 to N gives you N loops, with j=N in the final one.  In Python, for j in (1,N) gives you N-1 loops, with j=N-1 in the final one.  If you want N loops, you need to do for j in (1,N+1).  What language are you working in?

Comment: its written in pseudocode for algorithm analysis I'm thinking the + 1 is for the final condition check when using summations to count for loops?

Comment: @vincentbelkin:  then I don't understand the +1 either.

Comment: To be precise, the Python "for" command loops over the given list and nothing else. It's just that the command "range(a,b)", which is often used to generate the list, produces the numbers $a \le i < b$.